# Including two react application in one external web page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have two react application deployed as header and footer at some urls
header - `'someurl/header'`
footer - `'someurl/footer'`
I want to integrate this in a third application
I am able to integrate one of them at a time and both the react application is properly loaded but when i integrate both of them together only first application loads properly, second also renders but not as react component
Here is my code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin>. 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" 
crossorigin></script>
 <script  src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <script async> 

  fetch('http://url/footer')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
    document.getElementById("footer-container").appendChild(node);
  }); 

  
</script>

<script defer > 

 fetch('http://url/header')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then(data => {
    const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
      document.getElementById("header-container").appendChild(node)
         
    });
 
</script>
<div id="header-container"></div>
<div id="outer_div">outer content</div>
<div id="footer-container"></div>
```

Any help or hints is appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be reinventing microfrontends, so I would stick to some proven solution like webpack module federation or single-spa. With that in hands you may share the code between your micro apps (thus reducing performance impact) and gain better control over your app shell (which combines your micro apps together).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks for responding, actually other application is from third party provider we don't have control over that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling i found solution, detailed explanation

Unfortunately it is not possible to run several create-react-app applications on the same document because the JavaScript bundles resulting from a create-react-app project is not without side-effects: The bundled WebPack runtime writes an object on the global scope, which prevents to load several such bundles.

Somehow loading the scripts of the second React app has a side effect and prevents the bootstrapping of the first React app!

It turns out that the WebPack runtime is the problem here. The WebPack runtime adds an object to the global scope which is used to lazy-load chunks. The default name for this object is webpackJsonp

The Solution
The name of the webpackJsonp object can be configured in the WebPack config.

```
// webpack.config.dev.json
...
output: {
...
jsonpFunction: 'jsonpApp2'
}
```

I found solution from here
https://medium.jonasbandi.net/hosting-multiple-react-applications-on-the-same-document-c887df1a1fcd

Note: jsonpFunction not available in webpack 5, here is alternative in webpack 5 - `output.jsonpFunction -> output.chunkLoadingGlobal`
Have a look at this

```
module.exports = {
   //...
   output: {
      //...
      chunkLoadingGlobal: 'myCustomFunc',
   },
};
```